# BizTalk Enterprise Single Sign-On Service problem

Tags: biztalk

I recently had to change my active directory account password.

Ever since then I am unable to deploy BizTalk projects or put my Receive Locations in the stop state (Sendports & orchestrations is fine).

I noticed that my Enterprise Single Sign-On Service isn't running, if I try to start the service it complains about a login failure.

The thing is, you would think that it used my account to start this service and that it can't login anymore because of some old password or something. However I run the service with another user, namely: BiztalkUser. This user is set on the service and u can also see him in the biztalk server configuration.

Anyone have any ideas what I have to do? Cuz I can't do much anymore now.

Comment: What is the error message in the event log when you try to start the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agreed with the first paragraph of answer 1.  That would be the first option I would look to correct the problem.  The second option would be, restoring the master secret server.

See below;

Open a command prompt - Navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On\

Type in command - ssoconfig -restoresecret SSOXXXX.bak

(Where XXXX is a randomly generated name created with SSO was installed.  This is the SSO back-up file)

Enter the password - (Again you entered/created/accepted this when configuring SSO in the BizTalk configuration.)

Additionally you should create a new backup file if you have changed the account the SSO service runs under.

To create a new back-up file - ssoconfig -backupsecret latestbackup.dat

Comment: Is there any way to enter the password as a parameter? ... I'm wanting to sysprep a BizTalk virtual and one step is restoring the SSO

Answer (score 2):

The procedures for changing service accounts and password is clearly documented by Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561505(BTS.10).aspx please follow the steps outlined under "Enterprise Single Sign-On Service on Master Secret Server" to correct your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If SSO is running under your account and it stopped working when you changed the password, you need to update your password on the service's credentials.  You can do this in the serivces control panel.  If you have other BizTalk items running under your account, you will need to update them as well... host instances, application pools, etc.

BizTalk User may not not have the necessary permission to run SSO.  I'd suggest put the account back in that worked.  Comb the error log for other messages to help you diagnose th eproblem.  For furtherhelp, I'd suggest posting more specific details of your current problem here (ie. Error Messages, Log Files, etc.).